# Changing selection background color for ComboBox/BitmapComboBox

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

Is it possible to change selection background color for ComboBox/BitmapComboBox controls (wxpython/wxwidgets)?

[image]

My main concern is actually BitmapComboBox. The dark blue color interferes with icons having dark background.

Comment: Probably you need to implement your own: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_owner_drawn_combo_box.html

Comment: Did you try `SetBackgroundColour()` - e.g. myComboBox`.SetBackgroundColour("yellow")`

Comment: @PChemGuy, are you using "Dark Mode" theme?

Comment: Well, no, I don't.

Comment: Btw, take a look at this example: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_combo_ctrl.html#comboctrl_custompopup